# Flutter navigation goes to parent route instead of the child when using go router

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I am completely new to flutter and I recently added go router to my app to solve some issues with navigation.

Now, I am facing this issue which I couldn't find any answers for.

In the below code **home** is the parent of **goal**.

I am in a page where I would need to go to goal directly but when I do this

`context.go("goal")`

It goes to parent (which is home). I am not sure what I am doing wrong

This is my code:

```
GoRouter getRoutes() { 
    return GoRouter(initialLocation: '/', 
    observers: [ DoubleTapExitAppObserver() ], 
    routes: <RouteBase>[ 
    GoRoute(
    path: '/home', 
    name: 'home', 
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return HomeScreen();
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: 'home_with_count',
          path: ':gCount',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {

            int? goalCount = int.tryParse(
                state.pathParameters.containsKey("gCount")
                    ? state.pathParameters["gCount"] ?? ""
                    : "");
            return HomeScreen(
             gCount: gCount,
            );
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'home_profile_loaded',
          path: ':profileLoaded',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {

            bool profileLoaded = bool.tryParse(
                    state.pathParameters.containsKey("profileLoaded")
                        ? state.pathParameters["profileLoaded"] ?? ""
                        : "") ??
                false;
            return HomeScreen(
             profileLoaded: profileLoaded,
            );
          },
        ),

        GoRoute(
            name: 'goal',
            path: 'goal',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const GoalsListAndTrack();
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                name: 'allocate',
                path: 'allocate',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  Goal goal = state.extra as Goal;
                  return Allocate(goal: goal);
                },
              ),
              GoRoute(
                name: 'goal_details',
                path: 'goal_details',
                builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                  Goal goal = state.extra as Goal;
                  return GoalDetailsCard(goal: goal);
                },
              ),
            ]),

      ]),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/',
    // name: 'splash',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      return const SplashScreen();
    },
  ),
  GoRoute(
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
      return const LoginScreen();
    },
  ),
]);
}
```

Also, will help if there are any suggestion on above code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try this? `path: '/goal',`

Comment: @Akif Do you mean removing the nesting from home?

Comment: you should use `context.goNamed('goal')` instead `context.go('goal').

Comment: tried that as well @HarshSureja. It's still going to home

Comment: add '/' in every path of the screen then try.

Answer (score -1):

There many method you can navigate between screens.

Method 1: Use `Navigator.push()` for going to other pages and `Navigator.pop()` for returning to first route.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondRoute()),
  );
```

[Reade more](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Method 2: Use GetX its quite easy and professional for routing between pages in your application.

```
Get.to(NextScreen());
```

[Reade more](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Comment: I am using go router. I had no problem when using navigator. started facing this after moving to go router